# Zooming and position objects relative to mouseX in processing

Tags: processing

In this sketch, objects' positions are calculated from left to right from a fixed point. When zooming in or out, the objects will enlarge or decrease from left to right as well.

How do I calculate the offset I need to add to x so that when I zoom in or out the objects expand or shrink based on the mouse's X position (so mouseX will be the origin of zooming)?

The code for the sketch (takes a while to load because images are taken from the internet)

```java
PImage backgroundImage;
PFont font;
int x = 0;
int xoffset = 0;
int deltax = 5;
float scale = 512/30;
float deltascale = 0.02;
ArrayList<Object> ObjectList;
//String[] objectfile;
//String[] configfile;
//int savetimer = 0;

class Object {
  String name;
  float diameter;
  String unit;
  String sprite;
  PImage img;
  int wid;
  int hei;
  int xpos;

  Object(String Oname, float Odiameter, String Ounit, String Oimg) {
    name = Oname;
    diameter = Odiameter;
    unit = Ounit;
    img = loadImage(Oimg);
    sprite = Oimg;
    //img = loadImage(Oimg);
    wid = img.width;
    hei = img.height;
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(1500, 800);
  frameRate(200);
  //objectfile = loadStrings("objects.txt");
  //configfile = loadStrings("config.ini");
  //backgroundImage = loadImage("background.png");
  //font = createFont("Franklin Gothic Book Regular.ttf", 32);
  fill(255,255,255);
  textSize(32);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text("Images are loading (this may take a while)",700,400);
  ObjectList = new ArrayList();
  readObjects();
  //readConfig();
  //loadOffset();
}

void addObject(String Aname, float Adiameter, String Aunit, String Aimg) {
  //if (Aimg.equals("null")) {
  //  ObjectList.add(new Object(Aname, Adiameter, Aunit, "images/"+Aname+".png"));
  //} else {
  ObjectList.add(new Object(Aname, Adiameter, Aunit, Aimg));
  //}
}

void readObjects() {
  //for (int i = 0; i < objectfile.length; i++) {
  //  String[] currentObject = split(objectfile[i], ",");
  //  addObject(currentObject[0], float(currentObject[1]), currentObject[2], currentObject[3]);
  //}
  addObject("RED", 30, "m", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8f/1b/cc/8f1bcc72c81d1e9370597f7239ee476a.jpg");
  //addObject("ORANGE", 60, "m", "http://6iee.com/data/uploads/36/489075.jpg");
  addObject("YELLOW", 70, "m", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/aez1V.jpg");
  addObject("GREEN", 100, "m", "http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/mars.jpg");
  addObject("PURPLE", 105, "m", "http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/jupiter.png");
  addObject("PINK", 110, "m", "https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/4/4a/Alderaan.jpg");
  addObject("BROWN", 150, "m", "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/16/33/venus-151142_960_720.png");
  addObject("GRAY", 180, "m", "http://www.lpi.usra.edu/lpi_40th/images/1989/neptune.jpg");
  //addObject("WHITE", 200, "m", "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/19/log-in-sign-up-upload-clipart-Dpr48a-clipart.png");
  addObject("INDIGO", 300, "m", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Sun_in_February.jpg/155px-Sun_in_February.jpg");
  addObject("SKYBLUE", 301, "m", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Uranus_(Edited).jpg");
  addObject("BLUE", 1000, "m", "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/heman/images/3/36/Earth.jpg");
}

//void readConfig() {
//  for (int i = 0; i < configfile.length; i++) {
//    char slash = configfile[i].charAt(0);
//    if (slash != '/') {
//      //getting config values based on line number
//      if (i == 1) {
//        xoffset = int(configfile[i]);
//      } else if (i == 3) {
//        scale = float(configfile[i]);
//      }
//    }
//  }
//}


void draw() {
  //image(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
  fill(0,0,0);
  rect(0, 0, 1500, 800);

  int x = 0 + xoffset;
  for ( Object drawObject : ObjectList ) {   
    float dia = drawObject.diameter;
    //int drawWidthh = int(scale * dia);
    int drawWidth = int(scale * dia);
      int drawHeight = int(drawWidth * drawObject.hei / drawObject.wid);
    if (x+drawObject.img.width >= 0 && x <= 1500) {


      //checks if image is too small to be drawn 

      if (drawWidth > 0 && drawHeight > 0) {
        image(drawObject.img, x, 400-(drawHeight/2),drawWidth, drawHeight);
        //calculates font size relative to object's current size
        int textSize;
        //checks if the name or diameter is longer, then uses the longer one for calculation
        fill(255,255,255);
        if (drawObject.name.length() < str(drawObject.diameter).length()) {
          textSize = int(drawWidth/str(drawObject.diameter).length());
        } else {
          textSize = int(drawWidth/drawObject.name.length());
        }
        if (textSize > 0) {
          textSize(textSize);
          float texty = 418+(drawHeight/2);
          if (texty < (418+(drawHeight/2))) {
            texty = 418;
          }
          text(drawObject.name, x+(drawWidth/2), texty);
          text(drawObject.diameter+drawObject.unit, x+(drawWidth/2), texty+textSize);
        }
      }

    }
    drawObject.xpos = x;
      x += (drawWidth*0.08 + drawWidth);
    //display deltax
    textSize(32);
    text(str(deltax), 1450, 10);
    text(str(deltascale), 1450, 50);
    //display Saved
    //if (savetimer > 0) {
    //  text("Saved", 1450, 90);
    //  //text(str(savetimer),1450,130);
    //}
    //if (savetimer > 0) {
    //  //savetimer -= 1;
    //}
    println(str(scale));
  }
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event) {
  float e = event.getCount();
  if (e < 0) {
    scale *= (1 + deltascale);
  } else if (e > 0) {
    scale *= (1 - deltascale) ;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      xoffset += deltax;
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      xoffset -= deltax;
    } else if (keyCode == UP) {
      deltax += 5;
    } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      deltax -= 5;
    }
  }
  if (key == 'r') {
    //reloadObjects();
  } else if (key == 'q') {
    deltascale += 0.02;
  } else if (key == 'a') {
    deltascale -= 0.02;
  }
  if (deltax < 0) {
    deltax = 0;
  } else if (deltascale < 0) {
    deltascale = 0;
  }
}


void keyReleased() {  
  //reloadObjects();
}

void reloadObjects() {
  for ( Object reloadObject : ObjectList ) {
    float dia = reloadObject.diameter;
    //int drawWidthh = int(scale * dia);
    if (reloadObject.xpos > 0 && reloadObject.xpos+reloadObject.img.width <= 1500) {
      reloadObject.img = loadImage(reloadObject.sprite);
    }
  }
}
```

Use the mouse scroll wheel to zoom in and out and left and right arrow keys to navigate. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with a bunch of nested transformations keeping track of coordinate spaces using [`pushMatrix()`](http://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html)/[`popMatrix()`](http://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) calls.

You can follow the [2D Transformations Processing Tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) for more details.

Here's a quick commented sketch that explains the concept:

```
//a position to scale from
PVector mouse = new PVector();
//a scale value
float scale = 1.0;
//drawing dimensions - this depends on your actual content
float w = 400;
float h = 400;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  //move everything to centre
  translate(width * .5, height * .5);
  //isolate coordinate space
  pushMatrix();
  //move in the opposite direction by half of the drawing size => transform from drawing centre
  translate(-w * .5,-h * .5);
  //move to where the transformation centre should be (this can be mixed with the above, but I left it on two lines so it's easier to understand)
  translate(mouse.x,mouse.y);
  //transform from set position
  scale(scale);
  //move the transformation back
  translate(-mouse.x,-mouse.y);
  //draw what you need to draw
  drawStuff();
  //return to global coordinate space
  popMatrix();

  //draw a preview of the transformation centre
  if(mousePressed){
    fill(192,0,0);
    ellipse(mouse.x-width*.5,mouse.y-height*.5,35,35);
  }
}
//just a bunch of boxes as a placeholder
void drawStuff(){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 400; i++){
    int x = i % 20;
    int y = i / 20;
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x * 20, y * 20);
    rotate(radians(i));
    scale(sin(radians(i)) + 1.1);
    fill(i % 400);
    rect(0,0,15,15);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
//set the transformation centre
void mousePressed(){
  mouse.set(mouseX,mouseY);
}
//change scale by moving mouse on X axis
void mouseDragged(){
  scale = map(mouseX,0,width,0.25,2.0);
}
```

You can run a demo bellow:

```js
//a position to scale from
var mouse;
//a scale value
var scl = 1.0;
//drawing dimensions - this depends on your actual content
var w = 400;
var h = 400;

function setup(){
  mouse = createVector(0,0);
  createCanvas(400,400);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  //move everything to centre
  translate(width * .5, height * .5);
  //isolate coordinate space
  push();
  //move in the opposite direction by half of the drawing size => transform from drawing centre
  translate(-w * .5,-h * .5);
  //move to where the transformation centre should be (this can be mixed with the above, but I left it on two lines so it's easier to understand)
  translate(mouse.x,mouse.y);
  //transform from set position
  scale(scl);
  //move the transformation back
  translate(-mouse.x,-mouse.y);
  //draw what you need to draw
  drawStuff();
  //return to global coordinate space
  pop();
  
  //draw a preview of the transformation centre
  if(mousePressed){
    fill(192,0,0);
    ellipse(mouse.x-width*.5,mouse.y-height*.5,35,35);
  }
}
//just a bunch of boxes as a placeholder
function drawStuff(){
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 400; i++){
    var x = i % 20;
    var y = i / 20;
    push();
    translate(x * 20, y * 20);
    rotate(radians(i));
    scale(sin(radians(i)) + 1.1);
    fill(i % 400);
    rect(0,0,15,15);
    pop();
  }
}
//set the transformation centre
function mousePressed(){
  mouse.set(mouseX,mouseY);
}
//change scale by moving mouse on X axis
function mouseDragged(){
  scl = map(mouseX,0,width,0.25,2.0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.8/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: now that I understand how the Matrix stack thing works, I still don't know how much I should translate.

Comment: well done on getting the hang of matrix transformations, it takes a while to get used to :)
In terms of translation, as mentioned in the code comments above: 
1. translate to -drawing width/2,-drawing height/2 (to make the transformation centre the drawing centre)
2. translate to where you want the scaling centre to be
3. scale
4. translate back to (by using minus the dimensions you used to change the scaling centre to, at step 2).
HTH